# How to rotate only MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, rotation, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an application that on the iPod Touch/iPhone should not rotate. However, I do have an MFMaiComposeViewController for users to send bug reports. How my app is set up though, nothing can rotate, which is fine, except for this single view. How can I make this rotate to landscape. It is declared in one class like this:

```
//
//  LogbookSecondViewController.h
//  Logbook iDM
//
//  Created by Josiah Bruner on 9/20/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Infinite Software Technologies. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface LogbookSecondViewController : UIViewController  <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
        MFMailComposeViewController *email;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MFMailComposeViewController *email;

@end
```

In the .m

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"ToolsController - Send Email");
    NSString *MailTO = @"infinite@qualityservice.com";
    email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    email.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSArray *recipitants = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MailTO];
    // Subject
    [email setSubject:@"Bug/Problem/Suggestion, Logbook iDM"];

    [email setToRecipients:recipitants];

    // Present it
    [email setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [email setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [email dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

How can I allow only this view to rotate? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own class `MyCustomMailComposeViewController` (or whatever) that extends `MFMailComposeViewController`. All you need to add to the implementation of this class is:

```
// For iOS 6.0+
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

// For iOS 4.x and 5.x
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

This code assumes you want just landscape for the mail composer. Simply return YES if you want all orientations.

Then change:

```
email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

to:

```
email = [[MyCustomMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I will do. I was hoping for some method I could send to MFMailComposeViewController, but I don't think there is one. Thanks for your help.